# C# how to use the Parent class property in child class

Tags: c#

I have following class which has Parent class Shapes which has property Radius and i am accessing this property into its child class(HeaxGon) but it gives me error in child class ( get or set accessor expected)

Please advise.

```
class Shapes
{
    int _radius;

    public int Radius
    {
        get { return _radius; }
        set { _radius = value; }
    }
}

class HeaxGon:Shapes
{
    int points;
    public void SetRadius
    {
        **Radius=20;**
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two obvious syntax errors: 1) Those `**` are invalid 2) You forgot the parentheses required for a method declaration.

Comment: Your base class name really should be 'Shape', not 'Shapes', as it defines only one Shape, not a bunch of them (and even then it should be ShapeList). Semantics matter in clear programming.

Comment: There's no need for a SetRadius method. This is what the public set accessor of the Radius property does. Unless you actually want a method that just sets the radius to 20. In that case, I'd rename it to SetRadiusToTwenty or something similar. Finally, I think you might be trying to spell the word "Hexagon".

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you are trying to create a function called `SetRadius`, in which case, this is what it should look like:

```
public void SetRadius(int radius)
{
    this.Radius = radius;
}
```

Or if you really want to set it to `20` in all cases:

```
public void SetRadius()
{
    this.Radius = 20;
}
```

Comment: The `SetRadius` method is not necessary at all.

Comment: Yes, in its current form, it appears to be quite superfluous, but perhaps OP has something else in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote it badly, it should look like this:

```
class Shapes
{
    int _radius;

    public int Radius
    {
        get { return _radius; }
        set { _radius = value; }
    }
}


class HeaxGon:Shapes
{
    int points;

    public void SetRadius()
    {
        Radius=20;
    }
}
```

There's no need calling "this" like others have suggested.

Or simply work with the property you've already exposed in your base class

```
HeaxGon hg = new HeaxGon();
hg.Radius = 20;
```

This will call your setter you've specified in your base class (Shapes).

Comment: Thanks much appericated for your reply you catch the correct point i was missing the brackets of methods it should be SetRadius() instead of SetRadius..because compiler was thinking it as property..Thanks for all of your reply..

Answer (score 1):

Make `_radius` protected, and then simply call `this.Radius` in the child class.  So:

```
public class Shape
{
    protected int _radius;

    public int Radius
    {
        get { return _radius; }
        set { _radius = value; }
    }
}

public class Hexagon : Shape
{
    int _points;

    public void SetRadius(int radius)
    {
        this.Radius = radius;
    }
}
```